# How does time aggregation work in Sysdig?

Tags: sysdig

I have doubts on how time aggregation works in Sysdig. I have already referred to this documentation: https://sysdigdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/Monitor/pages/209027280/Data+Aggregation and I still find it vague.

As far as I understand, Sysdig polls the data at 10 seconds interval. That means there will be 1 data point per 10 seconds. That means, for each data point (i.e. 10 seconds), the average, minimum, maximum and rate is be the same. But looking at the charts below, the average and maximum is different, although the chart is already showing 10 seconds interval.

I can understand if let's say the data is polled every second, that means there are 10 data points for 10 seconds. then the average, max and minimum can be calculated from those 10 data points and the charts would make sense. but if there are only 1 data point per 10 second, I wonder how the average/max/min is calculated

[image: Average]

[image: Maximum]